# Detect backspace in empty UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, backspace

Is there any way to detect when the <kbd>Backspace</kbd>/<kbd>Delete</kbd> key is pressed in the iPhone keyboard on a `UITextField` that is empty?  I want to know when <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is pressed only if the `UITextField` is empty.

---

Based on the suggestion from @Alex Reynolds in a comment, I've added the following code while creating my text field:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
          selector:@selector(handleTextFieldChanged:)
              name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
            object:searchTextField];
```

This notification is received (`handleTextFieldChanged` function is called), but still not when I press the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key in an empty field.  Any ideas?

---

There seems to be some confusion around this question.  I want to receive a notification when the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key is pressed.  That's it.  But the solution must also work when the `UITextField` is already empty.

Comment: __2011/11 solution__ for empty UITextField using runtime trickery: http://bjhomer.blogspot.com/2011/11/detecting-backspace-in-uitextfield.html

Comment: For those who are struggling with this in SwiftUI you can find a full example   for a real use case here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76684922/detect-backspace-event-on-textfield-using-subclass-or-delegate-solution-integrat/77511527#77511527)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This may be a long shot but it could work.  Try setting the text field's text to a zero width space character `\u200B`.  When backspace is pressed on a text field that appears empty, it will actually delete your space.  Then you can just reinsert the space.

May not work if the user manages to move the caret to the left of the space.

Comment: Nice.  I agree that it's pretty hacky, but I was considering something like this as a last resort.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Andrew, this is the approach I decided to take.  It took a bit of code, but it's certainly effective.  Thanks for the help instead of trying to tell me that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: This technique may work on iPhone > 3.1.3, but it's hacky and may break on future versions, etc. I think I found a cleaner, more stable solution for [how to detect a delete keyboard key press on the iPhone/iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977934/detect-backspace-in-uitextfield/6637821#6637821).

Comment: Note that you should also remove the space character when the text field is not being edited. Otherwise your placeholder text won't be visible.

Comment: I can confirm that delete isn't detected if the user manages to move the cursor to the left of the space. If you can figure out how to fix that, then you should also subclass `UITextField` and implement `canPerformAction:withSender:` to `return NO` for `select:` and `selectAll:` actions when the text is equal to the string `@"\u200B"`.

Comment: ^I recall code for being able to detect the user's cursor location... you could search for that and then recall the `becomeFirstResponder` method if they move the cursor (so it moves back)

Comment: Problem is that this doesn't work for secure test fields. Any ideas how to handle that?

Comment: Sorry, but this idea is bad. It's incredible hacky and shouldn't be the accepted answer with 30 or so upvotes. I would subclass UITextField instead, like some of the other commenters have mentioned.

Answer (score 187):

### Swift 4:

---

Subclass `UITextField`:

```
// MyTextField.swift
import UIKit

protocol MyTextFieldDelegate: AnyObject {
    func textFieldDidDelete()
}

class MyTextField: UITextField {

    weak var myDelegate: MyTextFieldDelegate?

    override func deleteBackward() {
        super.deleteBackward()
        myDelegate?.textFieldDidDelete()
    }

}
```

Implementation:

```
// ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MyTextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // initialize textField
        let input = MyTextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 150, height: 40))

        // set viewController as "myDelegate"
        input.myDelegate = self

        // add textField to view
        view.addSubview(input)

        // focus the text field
        input.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func textFieldDidDelete() {
        print("delete")
    }

}
```

---

### Objective-C:

---

Subclass `UITextField`:

```
//Header
//MyTextField.h

//create delegate protocol
@protocol MyTextFieldDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)textFieldDidDelete;
@end

@interface MyTextField : UITextField<UIKeyInput>

//create "myDelegate"
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyTextFieldDelegate> myDelegate;
@end

//Implementation
#import "MyTextField.h"

@implementation MyTextField

- (void)deleteBackward {
    [super deleteBackward];

    if ([_myDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldDidDelete)]){
        [_myDelegate textFieldDidDelete];
    }
}

@end
```

Now simply add **MyTextFieldDelegate** to your `UIViewController` and set your `UITextFields` **myDelegate** to `self`:

```
//View Controller Header
#import "MyTextField.h"

//add "MyTextFieldDelegate" to you view controller
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MyTextFieldDelegate>
@end

//View Controller Implementation
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //initialize your text field
    MyTextField *input = 
     [[MyTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 30)];

    //set your view controller as "myDelegate"
    input.myDelegate = self;

    //add your text field to the view
    [self.view addSubview:input];
}

//MyTextField Delegate
- (void)textFieldDidDelete {
    NSLog(@"delete");
}
```

Comment: What will happen to my existing delegate methods in `ViewController ` class if I set my textfield's delegate to subclass of `UITextField` instead of `UIViewController`

Comment: `deleteBackward()` won't be called if you `return false` in `textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool`

Comment: For the called method (textFieldDidDelete) is there a non-hacky way to do something only when the text view (in my case) was already empty? I am using it to delete a row in a table but only when tapping backspace in an empty text view. My hacky solution is adding a bool to check. So the first time the text view is empty it changes the bool. The next time it deletes. (without the bool it deletes any time the text view is empty)

Answer (score 41):

Update: See [JacobCaraballo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15801258/242933) for an example that overrides `-[UITextField deleteBackward]`.

Check out [`UITextInput`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), specifically [`UIKeyInput`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIKeyInput) has a [`deleteBackward` delegate method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIKeyInput/deleteBackward) that *always* gets called when the delete key is pressed. If you're doing something simple, then you might consider just subclassing `UILabel` and making it conform to the `UIKeyInput` protocol, as done by [SimpleTextInput](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleTextInput/Introduction/Intro.html) and this [iPhone UIKeyInput Example](http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/04/21/iphone-os-3-2-uikeyinput-example/). *Note: `UITextInput` and its relatives (including `UIKeyInput`) are only available in iOS 3.2 and later.*

Answer (score 32):

Code like following:

```
@interface MyTextField : UITextField
@end

@implementation MyTextField

- (void)deleteBackward
{
    [super deleteBackward];

    //At here, you can handle backspace key pressed event even the text field is empty
}

@end
```

At last, do forget to change the Custom Class property of the Text Field to "MyTextField"

Answer (score 23):

Swift implementation:

```
import UIKit

// Extend from PinTextFieldDelegate instead of UITextFieldDelegate in your class
protocol PinTextFieldDelegate : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func didPressBackspace(_ textField: PinTextField)
}

class PinTextField: UITextField {

    override func deleteBackward() {
        super.deleteBackward()

        // If conforming to our extension protocol
        if let pinDelegate = self.delegate as? PinTextFieldDelegate {
            pinDelegate.didPressBackspace(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, may i know this method is recommended by apple or it's hack.
it seems undocumented for textfield.

Answer (score 18):

I've founded other way easier than `subclass` solution. Even its little bit strange but it works ok.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView 
        shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
        replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    const char * _char = [text cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    int isBackSpace = strcmp(_char, "\b");

    if (isBackSpace == -8) {
       // is backspace
    }

    return YES;
}
```

It's a little bit strange for result of compare is -8. Maybe I'll wrong in some point of `C Programming`. But its right work ;)

Comment: Backstroke isn't '\b' set. But if you carefully debugging then you will see '\0'. So I get the result 0 that is two values are equal in strcmp method. const char *stoke = [text cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; const char *backstroke = "\0";// this is equal to \b->"\x08"; strcmp(backstroke, stoke);

Comment: Also, by the definition of strcmp(s1, s2), returns 0 if s1 == s2, > 0 s1 is has lexicographically greater than s2 vice versa.

Comment: I don't understand how this could possibly work? @YoonLee: aren't you saying `strcmp` returns either `-1, 0, or 1`? That was my understanding.

Comment: in textview you always detect the backspace even if the there's no text, the UITextField is different

Comment: This is a `UITextViewDelegate` method, not `UITextFieldDelegate`.

Answer (score 13):

please use below code it will help you to detect keyboard delete key even if you textfield is empty.

**Objective C :**

`- (BOOL)keyboardInputShouldDelete:(UITextField *)textField { return YES; }`

**Swift :**

```
func keyboardInputShouldDelete(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool { return true }
```

Comment: Tx - just what I needed. But where is it documented??

Comment: absolutely best answer. This method is called only when back button is pressed on an empty text field

Comment: there's a consideration though. this method is not documented anywhere. Therefore  here we rely on some private iOS stuff. Which is not good

Answer (score 11):

Try the `delegate`

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
        shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
        replacementString:(NSString *)string {
```

Then check if the `range.length == 1` which seems to be the case when `backspace` is hit.

Comment: Only called when field is non-empty, though. Note the original question. :)

Answer (score 9):

Niklas Alvaeus's answer helped me out with a similar issue

I was limiting entry to a specific character set, but it was ignoring backspaces. 
So I had it check `range.length == 1` before trimming the `NSString`. If it is true, I just return the string and don't trim it. See below

```
 - (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField 
          shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
          replacementString:(NSString *)string
 {
     NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = 
      [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] 
         invertedSet];

    if (range.length == 1) {
       return string;
    }
    else {
       return ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0);
    }   
 }
```

Comment: The method expects a boolean and not a string as return value

Answer (score 5):

Yup, use below method to detect backspace, when textField is empty.

Need to add **UITextFieldDelegate**

yourTextField.delegate = self **(MUST REQUIRED)**

**Swift:**

> ```
> func keyboardInputShouldDelete(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool { 
>     return true
> }
> ```

**Objective C:**

> ```
> - (BOOL)keyboardInputShouldDelete:(UITextField *)textField { 
>     return YES; 
> }
> ```

Comment: This doesn't even call for me. All other delegate methods are getting called as and when for an event occurs.

Comment: @McDonal_11 I think you forgot to set textfield.delegate = self of textfield.

Comment: I have set. other UITextField's delegate methods are working fine. This one alone not working. What I miss ??

Answer (score 4):

For the ones who has problems about the [Jacob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15801258/242933) I implemented my textfield subclass as following and it works great!

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class HTTextField;

@protocol HTBackspaceDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)textFieldDidBackspace:(HTTextField*)textField;
@end

@interface HTTextField : UITextField<UIKeyInput>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<HTBackspaceDelegate> backspaceDelegate;

@end


#import "HTTextField.h"

@implementation HTTextField

- (void)deleteBackward {
    [super deleteBackward];
    if ([self.backspaceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldDidBackspace:)]){
        [self.backspaceDelegate textFieldDidBackspace:self];
    }
}

- (BOOL)keyboardInputShouldDelete:(UITextField *)textField {
    BOOL shouldDelete = YES;

    if ([UITextField instancesRespondToSelector:_cmd]) {
        BOOL (*keyboardInputShouldDelete)(id, SEL, UITextField *) = (BOOL (*)(id, SEL, UITextField *))[UITextField instanceMethodForSelector:_cmd];

        if (keyboardInputShouldDelete) {
            shouldDelete = keyboardInputShouldDelete(self, _cmd, textField);
        }
    }

    if (![textField.text length] && [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue] >= 8) {
        [self deleteBackward];
    }

    return shouldDelete;
}

@end
```

Comment: can you write the code for swift. I got some error "redundant confirmance to protoco uikeyinput"

Answer (score 3):

The best use that I have found for detecting backspace is detecting when the user has pressed backspace in an empty `UITextField`. For example, if you have 'bubbled' recipients in the mail app, when you hit backspace in the `UITextField`, it selects the last 'bubbled' recipient.

This can be done in a similar way to Jacob Caraballo's answer. But in Jacob's answer, if the `UITextField` has one character left when you hit backspace, by the time the delegate message is received, the `UITextField` will already be empty, so you're effectively detecting `backspace` on a text field with at most one characters.

Actually, if you want to detect `backspace` on a `UITextField` with exactly zero characters (empty), then you should send the message to the `delegate` before the call to `super deleteBackward`. For example:

```
#import "MyTextField.h"

//Text field that detects when backspace is hit with empty text
@implementation MyTextField

#pragma mark - UIKeyInput protocol
-(void)deleteBackward
{
  BOOL isTextFieldEmpty = (self.text.length == 0);
  if (isTextFieldEmpty) {
    if ([self.delegate 
         respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldDidHitBackspaceWithEmptyText:)]) {

        [self.delegate textFieldDidHitBackspaceWithEmptyText:self];
        }
    }
    [super deleteBackward];
}
@end
```

The interface for such a text field would look something like this:

```
@protocol MyTextFieldDelegate;

@interface MyTextField : UITextField
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<MyTextFieldDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol MyTextFieldDelegate <UITextFieldDelegate>
@optional
-(void)textFieldDidHitBackspaceWithEmptyText:(MyTextField *)textField;
@end
```

Comment: In order for this to work in iOS8 (where there's a bug causing this delegate method never to be called), please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25862878/893101 . More details on the ios8 bug: http://devforums.apple.com/message/1009150#1009150

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 6, the deleteBackward method is called on the UITextField when backspace is pressed, including when the field is empty. So you can subclass UITextField and provide your own deleteBackward implementation (invoking super's as well.)

I'm still supporting iOS 5 though so I'll need a combination of Andrew's answer and this.

Answer (score 2):

In .h file add UIKeyInput delegate

```
- (BOOL)keyboardInputShouldDelete:(UITextField *)textField {

if ([textField isEqual:_txtFirstDigit]) {

}else if([textField isEqual:_txtSecondDigit]) {
    [_txtFirstDigit becomeFirstResponder];

}else if([textField isEqual:_txtThirdDigit]) {
    [_txtSecondDigit becomeFirstResponder];

}else if([textField isEqual:_txtFourthDigit]) {
    [_txtThirdDigit becomeFirstResponder];
}
return YES;
}
```

improved Formatting

Answer (score 1):

:) just for the title "Detect backspace", where I use `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`.

I also meet the same question tonight, and following is my code to find it out:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
        shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
        replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [string length]]);
}
```

Because with `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`, user can only input Number or backspace, so when the length of string is 0, it must be backspace key.

Hope the above will do some help.

Comment: It's the same with any keyboard type.

Comment: how do i hook this method up to my text field?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to preconstruct what WILL BE in the text field or figure out what special character has been entered in the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method, I would suggest doing the following:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(manageSearchResultsDisplay) 
           withObject:nil 
           afterDelay:0];
```

This allows you to call a method directly after the current operation completes. What's cool about this is that, by the time it completes, the modified value will already be in the `UITextField`.  At that point, you can just check its length and/or validate based on what's there.

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing UITextField did not work for me on iOS 8.3, deleteBackward was never called.

Here is the solution I used, works on all iOS 8 versions and should work on other iOS versions as well

```
for textField in textFields {
            textField.text = " "
}

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if string == "" && textField.text == " "   {
            // Do stuff here
            return false
        }
        return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the similar solution with minor improvements that will tell me that if the text field has any value while the user has tapped the backspace. This is useful for my case when I should only focus on another text field if the text field is empty when backspace pressed.

```
protocol MyTextFieldDelegate : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidDelete(textField: MyTextField, hasValue: Bool)
}

override func deleteBackward() {
    let currentText = self.text ?? ""
    super.deleteBackward()
    let hasValue = currentText.isEmpty ? false : true
    if let delegate = self.delegate as? MyTextFieldDelegate {
        delegate.textFieldDidDelete(textField: self, hasValue: hasValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[The most poplar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15801258) is missing one thing — the ability to detect whether the text field was empty or not.

That is, when you override the deleteBackwards() method of a TextField subclass, you still don't know whether the text field was already empty. (Both before and after deleteBackwards(), `textField.text!` is an empty string: `""`)

Here's my improvement, with a check for emptiness prior to deletion.

#### 1. Create a delegate protocol that extends UITextFieldDelegate

```
protocol MyTextFieldDelegate: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, didDeleteBackwardAnd wasEmpty: Bool)
}
```

#### 2. Subclass UITextField

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {
    override func deleteBackward() {
        // see if text was empty
        let wasEmpty = text == nil || text! == ""

        // then perform normal behavior
        super.deleteBackward()

        // now, notify delegate (if existent)
        (delegate as? MyTextFieldDelegate)?.textField(self, didDeleteBackwardAnd: wasEmpty)
    }
}
```

#### 3. Implement your new delegate protocol

```
extension MyViewController: MyTextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, didDeleteBackwardAnd wasEmpty: Bool) {
        if wasEmpty {
            // do what you want here...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Comprehensive handler for textfield with single digit number for **Swift 5.1**:

- Assuming that you have outlet collection of textFields (with connected delegates as well)

## 1 Step

```
protocol MyTextFieldDelegate: class {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, didDeleteBackwardAnd wasEmpty: Bool) 
}

final class MyTextField: UITextField {

    weak var myDelegate: MyTextFieldDelegate?

    override func deleteBackward() {
        let wasEmpty = text == nil || text == ""

        // then perform normal behavior
        super.deleteBackward()

        // now, notify delegate (if existent)
        (delegate as? MyTextFieldDelegate)?.textField(self, didDeleteBackwardAnd: wasEmpty)
    }
}
```

## 2 Step

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var textFields: [MyTextField]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textFields.forEach {
            $0.delegate = self
            $0.myDelegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

## 3 Step

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate, MyTextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldHasChanged(with text: String, _ tag: Int, for textField: UITextField) {
        textField.text = text

        if let someTextField = (textFields.filter { $0.tag == tag }).first {
            someTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, didDeleteBackwardAnd wasEmpty: Bool) {
        // If the user was pressing backward and the value was empty, go to previous textField
        textFieldHasChanged(with: "", textField.tag - 1, for: textField)
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        // Restrict to only digits
        let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789").inverted
        let compSepByCharInSet = string.components(separatedBy: aSet)
        let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joined(separator: "")

        guard string == numberFiltered, let text = textField.text else { return false }

        if text.count >= 1 && string.isEmpty {
            // If the user is deleting the value
            textFieldHasChanged(with: "", textField.tag - 1, for: textField)
        } else {
            textFieldHasChanged(with: string, textField.tag + 1, for: textField)
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution based on @andrew idea:

somewhere, for example in viewDidLoad

```
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChanged(_:)), for: .editingDidBegin)
```

and then

```
    @objc func valueChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.text = "\u{200B}"
    }

    override func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        textField.text = string
        if string == "" {
            //backpaspace pressed 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are very helpful and I don't know why everyone is taking the protocol route. You can do it with much less code with call back function like-

**Swift 5.0 or above**

1. Make a custom textfield class extending the UITextField and override the deleteBackward function-

   class CustomTextField: UITextField {

   ```
    var backButtonPressedInEmptyTextField: (()->())?

    override func deleteBackward() {
        super.deleteBackward()
        if let text = self.text, text.count == 0{
            backButtonPressedInEmptyTextField?()
            print("Back space clicked when textfield is empty")
        }
    }
   ```

   }
2. Let's assume you want to do something based on that in your ViewController, `MyViewController`. So, in the `MyViewController`, just do following-

   class MyViewController: UIViewController{
   @IBOutlet weak var sampleTextField: CustomTextField!{
   didSet{
   sampleTextField.backButtonPressedInEmptyTextField =
   backButtonPressed()
   }
   }

   ```
    func backButtonPressed(){
        //do whatever you want
    }
   ```

   }

I feel with closure or call-back function, it is much cleaner.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
        shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
        replacementString:(NSString *)string       
{  
    if (![text hash] && ![textField.text length])  
        [self backspaceInEmptyTextField];  
}
```

of course the hash is for one character string.

Answer (score -2):

Using the TextField Delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Add the following code in above method to detect delete event

```
if(textField == YourTextField)
{
    if ([string length] == 0 && range.length > 0)
    {
        // Your Code after deletion of character
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
+ (BOOL)detectBackspaceOnly:(NSString *)string
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<string.length ; i++){
        unichar caract = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        if(caract != ' ' && caract != '\n')
            return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Maybe a little explanation where to put this?

Answer (score -3):

You can check the text of the text view/field to see if it's empty and make sure the replacement text is also empty in the shouldChangeTextIn delegate method.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if (textView.text == "" && text == "") {
        print("Backspace on empty text field.")
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score -4):

In `UITextViewDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)               textView:(UITextView *)textView 
        shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
                replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if(text isEqualToString:@"");
    {
        NSLog(@"press backspace.");
    }
}
```

it works ok for me.

update for Chinese simplified pinyin and Chinese handwriting input:

```
- (BOOL)               textView:(UITextView *)textView 
        shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
                replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if (range.length > 0 && [text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSLog(@"press Backspace.");
    }
    return YES;
}
```

base on the document says:

"If the user presses the `deleteKey`, the length of the range is 1 and an empty string object replaces that single character."

Comment: This question is about `UITextField`, not `UITextView`.

Answer (score -4):

To Keep it Simple here is the only condition u need to check

```
     if (range.length==1)
```