# Detect backspace in UITextField on a blank textfield

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, keypad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect backspace in UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977934/detect-backspace-in-uitextfield)

I am trying to detect the backspace key envent on my UITextfield which is empty. I saw this but could not figure it out. Any elaborate answer or code snippet would be helpful

[Detect backspace in UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977934/detect-backspace-in-uitextfield)

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you are trying to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 3):

I've found it not to be possible.

When the UITextField is empty, the following delegate method isn't called.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

I conquered this by constantly having a space in the field, and when I detect a backspace and the field only contains a space, I return NO in the delegate method.

```
if ([string isEqualToString:@""] && [textField.text isEqualToString:@" "]){
    // Backspace called on 'empty' field.
    return NO;
}
```

Visually, this is as good as the field being empty, and it's a workaround to the delegate method not being called on an empty field.

Hope that helps.

Comment: "I conquered this by constantly having a space in the field" - how you achieved that? Could you provide some sample code? What if user wrote in the textfield letter "a", then press backspace twice? When you inject space char to the field? Thanks!

Comment: I don't let the user use the delete key if there's only a space in the field - see the example code above.

Comment: There must be a better way to do this.

Comment: You could also try a zero-width character like \u200B

Answer (score 0):

:) just for the title "Detect backspace", where I use `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`.

I also meet the same question tonight, and following is my code to find it out:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [string length]]);
}
```

Because with `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`, user can only input Number or backspace, so when the length of string is 0, it must be backspace key.

Hope the above will do some help.