# How to detect UIKeyboard "backspace" button touch on UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboard

How can i detect backspace button pressed on `UIKeyboard`?

[image]

thanks

---

**EDIT**: Is there any keyboard delegate that returns key pressed value?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351358/detect-backspace-in-uitextfield-on-a-blank-textfield/4355245#4355245

Comment: for empty UITextField, detecting backspace check this:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45327651/996796

Answer (score 60, accepted):

if the UITextField is empty, the shouldChangeTextInRange delegate method is not called
You can subclass UITextField and override this method:

```
-(void)deleteBackward;
{
    [super deleteBackward];
    NSLog(@"BackSpace Detected");
}
```

since UITextField is compliant to the UITextInput protocol, this method is implemented, and you can override it to detect when backspace is pressed.
Then, you can write your own protocol/delegate method to alert your custom textfield delegate if the backspace is detected.

Comment: In my opinion, this should be the accepted answer!!!

Comment: +1 This answer is much simpler than the ones at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977934/detect-backspace-in-uitextfield.

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS8 - there's an Apple bug. Hopefully it'll be fixed in iOS8.1

Comment: Still not working on IOS8.1, have you found another solution  @AndrewBennett ?

Answer (score 29):

First of all your `UIViewController` that references the `UITextField` needs to conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` `protocol`. Then set your class as `delegate` to the `UITextField` (eg. `[myTextField setDelegate:self]` ). Then in your class you add the following. When a string of **""** is sent as the `replacementString` you know it's backspace.

```
(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
      shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
      replacementString:(NSString *)string
{                
    if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSLog(@"Backspace");            
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Temporary i'm inserting a zero space char on `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

```
textField.text = @"\u200B";
```

on backspace, it remove that chars, but graphically it's the same!

It's an hack, it works, but it hide placeholder text... not good...