# iOS - Detect backspace in keyboard when UITextField is empty

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect backspace in UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977934/detect-backspace-in-uitextfield)

I want to detect when backspace is pressed on the keyboard, even when a `UITextField` is empty.

I tried to use `ShouldChangeCharachtersInRange`, but it does not get called when the backspace is called and the text is empty.

How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977934/detect-backspace-in-uitextfield  and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818342/how-to-detect-uikeyboard-backspace-button-touch-on-uitextfield.These links provide you the solution you want

Comment: I'm trying to understand the logic here. shouldChangeCharactersInRange won't be called when pressing back if the field is empty because there aren't any characters to change.

Comment: I have a crossword in which every square is a TextField. What I want is that when the user presses the backspace key (when the TextField is empty), the focus will go the TextField that comes before it. This is why I need to detect when its called

Comment: @user721577 make every square a custom subclass of `UILabel` that conforms to the `UIKeyInput` protocol. Then, return `true` for `canBecomeFirstResponder`. `deleteBackward` always gets called, even when `hasText` returns `false`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6637821/242933

Answer (score -5):

Have you defined the delegate of UITextview in .h file or just assign delegate to self in .m file. Like textfield.delegate = self.

Comment: I have defined a UITextFieldDlegate in the .h

Comment: func keyboardInputShouldDelete(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        
        return true
    }