# Unable to use backspace key to delete a character from a textfield in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am implementing the following delegate method for UITextField:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

         NSString *integerPart = [textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][0];
         NSString *decimalPart = [textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][1];

         if ([integerPart length] > 8 || [decimalPart length] > 5) {
             return NO;//this clause is always called.
         }
...
}
```

I am trying to limit the number of digits entered in the textField to 6.  The problem I have is that if I enter a number with 6 digits after the decimal, and then try to press the backspace key on my device to delete the numbers, or need to make a correction inside the number, I'm unable to.

The reason is that whenever it comes to this point in my code, it notices that I have already entered 6 digits after the decimal (which is correct), and thus, nullifies my backspace key entry.  How do I maintain this limit of 6 digits after the decimal place, AND allow for editing of the number after reaching this limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't had a chance to test this, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16952218/3096507), string should be empty when a backspace is entered (which makes sense). So you should be able to do this.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

         // Always allow a backspace
         if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
              return YES;
         }

         // Otherwise check lengths
         NSString *integerPart = [textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][0];
         NSString *decimalPart = [textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][1];

         if ([integerPart length] > 8 || [decimalPart length] > 5) {
             return NO;//this clause is always called.
         }

         return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     //Construct the new string with new input
     NSString* newText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                           withString:text];

     NSString *integerPart = [newText componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][0];
     NSString *decimalPart = [newText componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][1];

     if ([integerPart length] > 8 || [decimalPart length] > 5) {
         return NO;//this clause is always called.
     }
```

I believe this is what you need. This will construct the new string that will be displayed in the textfield and you can evaluate that string.