# Any action method called tapped on back button of phone pad when text field is empty iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield

[image]

When the text field is empty and user tapped on the back button which action method will it call? My requirement is when the user tapped on the back button and text field is empty cursor will be on the previous text field.

Comment: can you show some code what you had try out

Comment: you need to track field previous textfield and call [previoustextfield becomeFirstResponse] in click of back button.

Comment: I am not getting any action methods which will call when text field is empty when text field have some text "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" called.

Comment: show some screen shot

Comment: @kkRocks but when text field is empty I am not getting any action methods

Comment: exactly what you want to do ?

Comment: is it navigation back button ?

Comment: I have 4 text fields. by default, keypad cursor is on the first text field. when the user enters any key, entered text will show on first field and cursor will go on the second screen. Now the user is taping on keypad back button. now cursor will be on the first field but any delegate methods are not calling when the user tapped on keypad back button.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12874641/3901620

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add a custom back button and define its action.

```
 UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)];
backButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;

[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barBackButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

navitem.hidesBackButton = YES;

navitem.leftBarButtonItems = @[barBackButtonItem];
```

Comment: I am talking about keypad back button.

Comment: by back button do you mean backspace button?