# Objective-C Runtime: Swizzled method name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, objective-c-runtime

In an attempt to [Detect backspace in UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977934/detect-backspace-in-uitextfield), 
I've tried subclassing [`UITextField` and overriding `-[UIKeyInput deleteBackward]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958574/can-i-detect-the-delete-key-even-if-the-uitextfield-is-empty/5958770#5958770), but it never gets called. So, I'm suspecting `UITextField` swizzles `deleteBackward` to another method name.

Using the [Objective-C Runtime](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html), how can I determine which method name `deleteBackward` has been swizzled to? Then, how can I change the implementation so that `UITextField` will call `[self.delegate textField:self shouldChangeCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0) replacementString:@""]` when the delete key is pressed when it's empty.

Also, will this kind of metaprogramming get my app rejected from the App Store?

Comment: +1, because this is a deceptively hard question.

Answer (score 4):

Swizzling doesn't change the name of a method. If it did, it would be impossible to call the method, since the runtime finds the implementation using the name. All it does is change the address of the code which is run when you call a specific method.

My guess as to why the `deleteBackward` method isn't being called is that the input system is using a method from the more complicated [UITextInput](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInput) protocol instead, most likely `replaceRange:withText:`. Try swizzling that and performing your call when the `text` argument is an empty string. Also make sure your swizzling function doesn't return an error.

Comment: But [`UITextInput`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInput) conforms to [`UIKeyInput`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIKeyInput), which requires `deleteBackward` to be implemented. So, shouldn't that require `UITextField` to implement `deleteBackward`?

Comment: Also, in my subclass (and in my category) of `UITextField`, I implemented `replaceRange:withText:` with just an `NSLog` to see if it gets called, and it doesn't.

Comment: @Matt Yes, it requires that `deleteBackward` is implemented, but it doesn't necessarily mean it will be used. It was just a possibility. However, rereading your question, I noticed that you are only worried about when it is empty. Does either method get called if its not empty? Maybe the input system doesn't tell the text field about the keypress if it's empty.

Comment: I've played with this a fair bit; neither method gets called when you backspace on an empty textfield.