# UITextField jump to previous

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I have two UITextField's in my view to let the user enter a zipcode in format 1234AA

- UITextField 1 : for the number part with number pad
- UITextField 2 : for the letters (regular keyboard)

I was able to automatically jump to the second textfield when the user has entered four digits.

I customized this method for that:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Now my question is, is there a way to automatically jump back from textfield 2 to textfield 1 when the users presses the delete key while textfield 2 is empty.

I couldn't get this working because when textfield 2 is empty the above method isn't called.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ***textField.tag*** to identify your textFields.  Example if you assign tags 0 and 1 for texFields 1 and 2 respectively.

```
// You could do this in the textFieldDidBeginEditing method //

If (textField.tag == 0)
   {
  //Now the first textField must be active//
  // do the method you had posted above//
    }

If (textField.tag ==1)
                   {
  //Now the second textField must be active//

    }
```

The logic behind checking for the keyboard events is provided in the link below. Alternatively you could also use NSNotification to check for keyboard events.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleTextFieldChanged:)name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
        object:searchTextField];
```

Check this question on Stack Overflow for detecting BackSpace on Empty UITextField
[Detect backspace in UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977934/detect-backspace-in-uitextfield)

You could also use this tutorial to detect pressed keys and check for BackSpace and transfer control back to textField 1.
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/11725