# Keypress event in textfields

Tags: iphone

I have a situation where I need to have a "backspace" key press event inside a textfield. Is there a direct method to use this event, or do I have to implement the textfield delegate and apply some logics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a delegate essentially. You can set up a notification like below,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
          selector:@selector(handleTextFieldChanged:)
              name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
            object:searchTextField];
```

and you can handle the change by implementing handleTextFieldChanged.

This may help [Detect backspace in UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977934/detect-backspace-in-uitextfield)