# How to get delete (backspace) event from UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview, drag, backspace

I have simple solution.

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
    if(range.length == 1 && [text length] == 0){
        NSLog(@"backspace");
    }
}
```

However, If the user to delete the dragged text?

Above code will not be obtain event.

But, article detail view of facebook does not have this problem.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371254/how-to-detect-delete-key-on-an-uitextfield-in-ios-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    if (range.length > 0 && [string isEqualToString:@""]) {
       NSLog(@"Backspace");            
    }
```

Comment: This code do not get if the text is deleted "abcd\nefg". Because textview delegate method 'shouldChangeTextInRange ' will only return the last Text..