# UITextView/UITextField: How to check if a delete key is pressed in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield

As the title in this question. I want to check if delete key is pressed. I knew about this code below:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

     if string.characters.count == 0 && range.length > 0 {
          // Back pressed
          print("OK")
     }

     return true
}
```

But when the textField is empty, this function is not called. So, how to check that case?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to check a backspace character when the textfield is empty?

Comment: This function will not work if textField is empty.

Comment: @unkgd When textfield is empty and the backspace was pressed. I will remove something like tag/hashtag...

Comment: @TienLe, did you check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977934/detect-backspace-in-uitextfield

Comment: @PremaJanoti: Yes, the function is not called

Comment: @unkgd: I know the charactor \u200B. This is backspace. But how to detect this charactor?

Comment: What they are mentioning in the post, is that you should use an empty character placeholder when the last character is deleted, this way you always have a character which is "empty" in the text field, and each time you delete it, put a new replacement

Comment: @unkgd: I understand. Thanks for your answer. Have a good day :)

override func deleteBackward() {  super.deleteBackward()} 
It works

Answer (score -1):

You can try it

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

      if (string.Charecter.count==0) { //Delete any cases
       if(range.length > 1){
          //Delete whole word
       }
       else if(range.length == 1){
          //Delete single letter
       }
       else if(range.length == 0){
          //Tap delete key when textField empty
       }  
    }  
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the function is not called

Comment: @TienLe you have to delegate the TextField. Use `UITextFieldDelegte` and then `viewDidLoad()` call this `myTextField.delegate = self`