# Detect backspace in empty UITextField Swift Working Sample

Tags: swift

I know that this question may sounds duplicate, but looking at the several answer, nothing is working for me yet.

Basically I have a Quizz App, a question is shown and the user needs to fill several `UITextFields` to answer the question (i.e. if the answer is VENICE, 6 `UITextFields` will be shown, 1 per letter).

It was able to detect one character in the `UITextFields` and once the user hits a key it will jump to the following `UITextField`. I use the tag of the `UITextField` and the method `becomeFirstResponder`.

The problem is that I will like to detect the backspace when a `UITextField` is empty so I will jump to the previous `UITextField`.

I have tried this solution from Jacob Caraballo ([Detect backspace in empty UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977934/detect-backspace-in-empty-uitextfield/15801258#15801258)) but I am not sure, how to use it with my existing UITextField.

For example, I have tried:

```
 // @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField1:MyTextField!
```

But calling the delegate

```
textField1.myDelegate = self
```

It crashes

I also notice, that using the Jacob's solution I won't be able to check which `UITextField` was used as the `func textFieldDidDelete()` doesn't not have an `UITextField` as parameter and I will need to check its tag i.e.

```
If textField.tag == 5 {
   textField4.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Any help on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Jacob's solution, the `deleteBackward` method will be called with the current `UITextField` instance. So you can add a protocol to that `UITextField` class and pass it back to your view.
Something like this:

```
protocol MyTextFieldDelegate: class {
   func backwardDetected(textField: MyTextField)
}

class MyTextField: UITextField {
   weak var myTextFieldDelegate: MyTextFieldDelegate?

   override func deleteBackward() {
     super.deleteBackward()

     self.myTextFieldDelegate?.backwardDetected(textField: self)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lyric, but how I have to declare my UITextField and how I set the delegate? @IBOutlet weak var textField1:MyTextField! declaration for each UITextField is correct? and How I set the delegate for each UITextField? Sorry, I am a little bit lost with this

Comment: each of your delegate will have to be of type `MyTextField`. and for each of them add this line: self.textField1.myTextFieldDelegate = self

Comment: after that implement the func backwardDetected(textField: MyTextField) method in your controller/view

Comment: Sorry Lyric, I have an error on the class. It says: Value of type 'UITextFieldDelegate' has no member 'backwardDetected'

Comment: fixed my code above. Its should be : self.myTextFieldDelegate?.backwardDetected(textField: self). Sorry about that ;)

Comment: Thanks Lyric,and thanks a lot a lot for your patient :-). Now, when setting the delegate I have an error when trying to run the application in the line `self.textField1.myTextFieldDelegate = self`, the app is builded that just when it starts it throws the error Thread `1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)`. Any ideas why? I have created a new app from the scratch

Comment: I think the problem is on the declaration of the IBOutlets, to create an IBOutlet I Control + Drag my UITextView, and on Type I change default one (UITextField) to MyTextField, probably this is the problem, but I don't know another way to create the IBOutlets

Comment: I solve it changing in the Identity Inspector from UITextField to MyTextField. Thanks a lot Lirik!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Happy to help! @JorgeFernández