# Detect backspace in empty Entry field in .Net MAUI

Tags: maui

In my .Net MAUI application I have an email verification screen with four entry fields. I listen for `TextChanged` events on these fields and move the focus to the next field when the user enters their code. My problem is that this doesn't work for deleting. If the focus is on an empty entry field and the user press backspace I want to move focus to the previous field, but `TextChanged` is not fired because the text is not changed.

[image]

I have a working solution for Windows where I have subclassed Entry and listen for `KeyUp` events from the native view, but I can't figure out create the same functionality  for Mac and iOS.

```
public class MyEntry : Entry
{
    public event EventHandler KeyBackspaceUp;

    public MyEntry()
    {
        Loaded += (o, e) =>
        {
                    
#if WINDOWS
            UIElement? nativeView = Handler?.PlatformView as UIElement;
            if (nativeView != null)
            {
                nativeView.KeyUp += (o, e) =>
                {
                    if(e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Back)
                    {
                        KeyBackspaceUp?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                };
            }
#elif IOS || MACCATALYST
            UITextField nativeView = Handler?.PlatformView as UITextField;
            if (nativeView != null) 
            {
                // TODO: Add backspace detection for Mac and iOS                
            }
#endif
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You may override [DeleteBackward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uitextfield.deletebackward?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12). Also refer to [Detect backspace in empty UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977934/detect-backspace-in-empty-uitextfield).

Answer (score 0):

I created the FreakyCodeView for this not sure if its relevant to you in terms of the design but you can use the code in it

https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="Maui.FreakyControls.FreakyCodeView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="this">
    <Grid>
        <Entry x:Name="hiddenTextEntry" Opacity="0">
            <Entry.FontSize>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Default="18">
                    <On Platform="Android" Value="18" />
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="22" />
                </OnPlatform>
            </Entry.FontSize>
        </Entry>
        <HorizontalStackLayout x:Name="CodeItemContainer" Spacing="{Binding ItemSpacing, Source={x:Reference this}}">
            <HorizontalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
            </HorizontalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

And its code behind

```
public partial class FreakyCodeView : ContentView
{
    #region Events

    public event EventHandler<FreakyCodeCompletedEventArgs> CodeEntryCompleted;

    #endregion Events

    #region Constructor and Initializations

    public FreakyCodeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        hiddenTextEntry.TextChanged += FreakyCodeView_TextChanged;
        hiddenTextEntry.Focused += HiddenTextEntry_Focused;
        hiddenTextEntry.Unfocused += HiddenTextEntry_Unfocused;
        Initialize();
    }

    private void HiddenTextEntry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        var CodeItemArray = CodeItemContainer.Children.Select(x => x as CodeView).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < CodeLength; i++)
        {
            CodeItemArray[i].UnfocusAnimate();
        }
    }

    private void HiddenTextEntry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        var length = CodeValue is null ? 0 : CodeValue.Length;
        hiddenTextEntry.CursorPosition = length;

        var CodeItemArray = CodeItemContainer.Children.Select(x => x as CodeView).ToArray();

        if (length == CodeLength)
        {
            CodeItemArray[length - 1].FocusAnimate();
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CodeLength; i++)
            {
                if (i == length)
                {
                    CodeItemArray[i].FocusAnimate();
                }
                else
                {
                    CodeItemArray[i].UnfocusAnimate();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion Constructor and Initializations

    #region Methods

    public void Initialize()
    {
        hiddenTextEntry.MaxLength = CodeLength;
        SetInputType(CodeInputType);

        var count = CodeItemContainer.Children.Count;

        if (count < CodeLength)
        {
            int newItemesToAdd = CodeLength - count;
            char[] CodeCharsArray = CodeValue.ToCharArray();

            for (int i = 1; i <= newItemesToAdd; i++)
            {
                CodeView container = CreateItem();
                CodeItemContainer.Children.Add(container);
                if (CodeValue.Length >= CodeLength)
                {
                    container.SetValueWithAnimation(CodeCharsArray[CodeView.DefaultCodeLength + i - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (count > CodeLength)
        {
            int ItemesToRemove = count - CodeLength;
            for (int i = 1; i <= ItemesToRemove; i++)
            {
                CodeItemContainer.Children.RemoveAt(CodeItemContainer.Children.Count - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public new void Focus()
    {
        base.Focus();
        hiddenTextEntry.Focus();
    }

    private CodeView CreateItem(char? charValue = null)
    {
        CodeView container = new()
        {
            ItemFocusColor = ItemFocusColor,
            FocusAnimationType = ItemFocusAnimation,
        };
        container.SetBinding(Border.HeightRequestProperty, new Binding("ItemSize", source: this));
        container.SetBinding(Border.WidthRequestProperty, new Binding("ItemSize", source: this));
        container.SetBinding(Border.StrokeThicknessProperty, new Binding("ItemBorderWidth", source: this));
        container.Item.SetBinding(Border.BackgroundColorProperty, new Binding("ItemBackgroundColor", source: this));
        container.CharLabel.FontSize = ItemSize / 2;
        container.SecureMode(IsPassword);
        container.SetColor(Color, ItemBorderColor);
        container.SetRadius(ItemShape);
        if (charValue.HasValue)
        {
            container.SetValueWithAnimation(charValue.Value);
        }
        return container;
    }

    #endregion Methods

    #region Events

    private void FreakyCodeView_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CodeValue = e.NewTextValue;

        if (e.NewTextValue.Length >= CodeLength)
        {
            if (ShouldAutoDismissKeyboard)
            {
                hiddenTextEntry.DismissSoftKeyboard();
            }
            CodeEntryCompleted?.Invoke(this, new FreakyCodeCompletedEventArgs(CodeValue));
            CodeEntryCompletedCommand.ExecuteCommandIfAvailable(CodeValue);
        }
    }

    #endregion Events

    #region BindableProperties

    public string CodeValue
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(CodeValueProperty);
        set => SetValue(CodeValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CodeValueProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create(
           nameof(CodeValue),
           typeof(string),
           typeof(FreakyCodeView),
           string.Empty,
           defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
           propertyChanged: CodeValuePropertyChanged);

    private static async void CodeValuePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        try
        {
            var control = (FreakyCodeView)bindable;

            string newCode = newValue.ToString();
            string oldCode = oldValue.ToString();

            int newCodeLength = newCode.Length;
            int oldCodeLength = oldCode.Length;

            if (newCodeLength == 0 && oldCodeLength == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            char[] newCodeChars = newCode.ToCharArray();

            control.hiddenTextEntry.Text = newCode;
            var CodeItemArray = control.CodeItemContainer.Children.Select(x => x as CodeView).ToArray();

            bool isCodeEnteredProgramatically = (oldCodeLength == 0 && newCodeLength == control.CodeLength) || newCodeLength == oldCodeLength;

            if (isCodeEnteredProgramatically)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < control.CodeLength; i++)
                {
                    CodeItemArray[i].ClearValueWithAnimation();
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < control.CodeLength; i++)
            {
                if (i < newCodeLength)
                {
                    if (isCodeEnteredProgramatically)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(50);
                    }

                    CodeItemArray[i].SetValueWithAnimation(newCodeChars[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (CodeItemArray.Length >= control.CodeLength)
                    {
                        CodeItemArray[i].ClearValueWithAnimation();
                        CodeItemArray[i].UnfocusAnimate();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (control.hiddenTextEntry.IsFocused)
            {
                if (newCodeLength < control.CodeLength)
                {
                    CodeItemArray[newCodeLength].FocusAnimate();
                }
                else if (newCodeLength == control.CodeLength)
                {
                    CodeItemArray[newCodeLength - 1].FocusAnimate();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public int CodeLength
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(CodeLengthProperty);
        set => SetValue(CodeLengthProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CodeLengthProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(
          nameof(CodeLength),
          typeof(int),
          typeof(FreakyCodeView),
          CodeView.DefaultCodeLength,
          defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
          propertyChanged: CodeLengthPropertyChanged);

    private static void CodeLengthPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if ((int)newValue <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }
       ((FreakyCodeView)bindable).Initialize();
    }

    public KeyboardType CodeInputType
    {
        get => (KeyboardType)GetValue(CodeInputTypeProperty);
        set => SetValue(CodeInputTypeProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CodeInputTypeProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create(
           nameof(CodeInputType),
           typeof(KeyboardType),
           typeof(FreakyCodeView),
           KeyboardType.Numeric,
           defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
           propertyChanged: CodeInputTypePropertyChanged);

    private static void CodeInputTypePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = ((FreakyCodeView)bindable);
        control.SetInputType((KeyboardType)newValue);
    }

    public void SetInputType(KeyboardType inputKeyboardType)
    {
        if (inputKeyboardType == KeyboardType.Numeric)
        {
            hiddenTextEntry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
        }
        else if (inputKeyboardType == KeyboardType.AlphaNumeric)
        {
            hiddenTextEntry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Create(0);
        }
    }

    public ICommand CodeEntryCompletedCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CodeEntryCompletedCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CodeEntryCompletedCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CodeEntryCompletedCommandProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create(
          nameof(CodeEntryCompletedCommand),
          typeof(ICommand),
          typeof(FreakyCodeView),
          null);

    public bool IsPassword
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsPasswordProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsPasswordProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsPasswordProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(
          nameof(IsPassword),
          typeof(bool),
          typeof(FreakyCodeView),
          true,
          defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
          propertyChanged: IsPasswordPropertyChanged);

    private static void IsPasswordPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = ((FreakyCodeView)bindable);
        foreach (var x in control.CodeItemContainer.Children)
        {
            var container = (CodeView)x;
            container.SecureMode((bool)newValue);
        }
    }

    public Color Color
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(ColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(ColorProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ColorProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(
          nameof(Color),
          typeof(Color),
          typeof(FreakyCodeView),
          Colors.Black,
          defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
          propertyChanged: ColorPropertyChanged);

    private static void ColorPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = ((FreakyCodeView)bindable);
        foreach (var x in control.CodeItemContainer.Children)
        {
            var container = (CodeView)x;
            container.SetColor(color: (Color)newValue, ItemBorderColor: control.ItemBorderColor);
        }
    }

    public double ItemSpacing
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ItemSpacingProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemSpacingProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemSpacingProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(
          nameof(ItemSpacing),
          typeof(double),
          typeof(FreakyCodeView),
          CodeView.DefaultItemSpacing);

    public double ItemSize
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ItemSizeProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemSizeProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemSizeProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(
          nameof(ItemSize),
          typeof(double),
          typeof(FreakyCodeView),
          CodeView.DefaultItemSize);

    public ItemShape ItemShape
    {
        get => (ItemShape)GetValue(ItemShapeProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemShapeProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemShapeProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create(
           nameof(ItemShape),
           typeof(ItemShape),
           typeof(FreakyCodeView),
           ItemShape.Circle,
           defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
           propertyChanged: ItemShapePropertyChanged);

    private static void ItemShapePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = ((FreakyCodeView)bindable);
        foreach (var x in control.CodeItemContainer.Children)
        {
            var container = (CodeView)x;
            container.SetRadius((ItemShape)newValue);
        }
    }

    public Color ItemFocusColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(ItemFocusColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemFocusColorProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemFocusColorProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(
          nameof(ItemFocusColor),
          typeof(Color),
          typeof(FreakyCodeView),
          Colors.Black,
          defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
          propertyChanged: ItemFocusColorPropertyChanged);

    private static void ItemFocusColorPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = ((FreakyCodeView)bindable);
        foreach (var x in control.CodeItemContainer.Children)
        {
            var container = (CodeView)x;
            container.ItemFocusColor = (Color)newValue;
        }
    }

    public FocusAnimation ItemFocusAnimation
    {
        get => (FocusAnimation)GetValue(ItemFocusAnimationProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemFocusAnimationProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemFocusAnimationProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create(
           nameof(ItemFocusAnimation),
           typeof(FocusAnimation),
           typeof(FreakyCodeView),
           default(FocusAnimation),
           defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
           propertyChanged: ItemFocusAnimationPropertyChanged);

    private static void ItemFocusAnimationPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = ((FreakyCodeView)bindable);
        foreach (var x in control.CodeItemContainer.Children)
        {
            var container = (CodeView)x;
            container.FocusAnimationType = (FocusAnimation)newValue;
        }
    }

    public Color ItemBorderColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(ItemBorderColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemBorderColorProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemBorderColorProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(
          nameof(ItemBorderColor),
          typeof(Color),
          typeof(FreakyCodeView),
          Colors.Black,
          defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
          propertyChanged: ItemBorderColorPropertyChanged);

    private static void ItemBorderColorPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (FreakyCodeView)bindable;
        if (control.Color != (Color)newValue)
        {
            foreach (var x in ((FreakyCodeView)bindable).CodeItemContainer.Children)
            {
                var container = (CodeView)x;
                container.SetColor(color: control.Color, ItemBorderColor: (Color)newValue);
            }
        }
    }

    public Color ItemBackgroundColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(ItemBackgroundColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemBackgroundColorProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemBackgroundColorProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(
          nameof(ItemBackgroundColor),
          typeof(Color),
          typeof(FreakyCodeView),
          default(Color),
          defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
          propertyChanged: ItemBackgroundColorPropertyChanged);

    private static void ItemBackgroundColorPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        foreach (var x in ((FreakyCodeView)bindable).CodeItemContainer.Children)
        {
            var container = (CodeView)x;
            container.Item.BackgroundColor = (Color)newValue;
        }
    }

    public bool ShouldAutoDismissKeyboard
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(ShouldAutoDismissKeyboardProperty);
        set => SetValue(ShouldAutoDismissKeyboardProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ShouldAutoDismissKeyboardProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(
          nameof(ShouldAutoDismissKeyboard),
          typeof(bool),
          typeof(FreakyCodeView),
          true);

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsEnabled)
        {
            this.Focus();
        }
    }

    public double ItemBorderWidth
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ItemBorderWidthProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemBorderWidthProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemBorderWidthProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(
          nameof(ItemBorderWidth),
          typeof(double),
          typeof(FreakyCodeView),
          5.0,
          defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    [TypeConverter(typeof(FontSizeConverter))]
    public double FontSize
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty);
        set => SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(
          nameof(FontSize),
          typeof(double),
          typeof(FreakyCodeView),
          defaultValueCreator: FontSizeDefaultValueCreator,
          defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
          propertyChanged: OnFontSizeChanged);

    private static object FontSizeDefaultValueCreator(BindableObject bindable)
    {
        var itemSize = (double)ItemSizeProperty.DefaultValue;
        double fontSize = itemSize / 2.0;
        return fontSize;
    }

    private static void OnFontSizeChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = ((FreakyCodeView)bindable);
        foreach (var x in control.CodeItemContainer.Children)
        {
            var container = (CodeView)x;
            container.CharLabel.FontSize = (double)newValue;
        }
    }

    public string FontFamily
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(FontFamilyProperty);
        set => SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty FontFamilyProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
      nameof(FontFamily),
      typeof(string),
      typeof(FreakyCodeView),
      propertyChanged: OnFontFamilyChanged);

    private static void OnFontFamilyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = ((FreakyCodeView)bindable);
        foreach (var x in control.CodeItemContainer.Children)
        {
            var container = (CodeView)x;
            container.CharLabel.FontFamily = newValue?.ToString();
        }
    }

    #endregion BindableProperties
}
```

Comment: On the FreakyCodeView project page it says that it's for iOS and Android. Does it also work on Windows and Mac Catalyst which is my target platforms?

Comment: Since it is based on a ContentView, it might I just don't officially support it, because I don't have the time and the devices to test it